# ajax not working on mobile device

Tags: ajax

The following code works fine in my desktop browser but not in Mobile Safari or Mobile Chrome. I am using jQueryMobile 1.4.3. Any ideas?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(".editWidget").click(function() {
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: url,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    jQuery.each(data.userdata, function(i, info){
                        //do stuff...
                    });
                },
                error: function(XHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });

        }); 
});
```

It returns a "ParseError" then says:

JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "demo".

I have validated that the json I am returning is valid:

```
{ "userdata": [
            {
                "content":"Copyright 2015 rave7.",
                "title":"Sample Text",
                "id":"18",
                "modinfo":"Last update by Demo User on Sat Feb 07, 2015 at 10:45 PM",
                "postback_id":"",
                "postback_type":""
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Older browsers don't have native JSON support. You'll likely have to include it [manually](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js).

Comment: Another odd thing is that it immediately goes to the error handler and it was working before then magically it just stopped working a few weeks ago and I can't get it to work now. I m using the latest mobile browsers on my iPhone.